# How to transcode a video using python and ffmpeg library (no commandline call)

Tags: python, encoding, ffmpeg, py2exe, transcoding

I would like to transcode a video using python and ffmpeg. But I dont want to use a command line call like 
    call(ffmpeg -i ....")

I will need to deploy the resulting application using py2exe, thus cannot use call method.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: py2exec doesn't support embedded resources?

Comment: What is the problem with calling ffmpeg in a separate process?

Comment: Isn't this a job for [`pyffmpeg`](http://code.google.com/p/pyffmpeg/)?

Comment: i discovered pyffmpeg before, but they have only examples about how to extract images.. Though, I did not dig deeper. Chris, do you know some examples relevant to transcoding and pyffmpeg?

Answer (score 0):

opencv has a VideoCapture (reading) and VideoWriter class and it's basically wrapper for ffmpeg but works great for me. Although i prefer using subprocess module to invoke ffmpeg.exe because I have more options to encoding etc.

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html